# Access denied writing to VS project .suo when trying to merge branches with TFS & GIT

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I am trying to merge a branch with the master. Branch structure:

```
master
    v0.43
```

My important changes are in v0.43. After making a commit in v0.43 I attempt to merge v0.43 to master. I receive the following error:

> An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2.
>   Category = Invalid (Error). Could not open
>   'C:/Users/Me/Source/Repos/MyüProject XXX/MyüProject XXX/XXX XXX
>   X.v12.suo' for writing: Access is denied.

There is no additional information in the Output pane.

**I also get the above error message when simply trying to change from the v0.43 branch to the master branch.** Basically, I'm stuck in the v0.43 branch.

Please note that the "X"s obscure alpha characters in the actual project name. Are the spaces valid? Is ü valid? If the folder and file names are valid, and the special character is valid, why is Access Denied? Or should the merge need to access this file at all?

I understand it is a Visual Studio User Settings file. I am fairly sure it is not included in the GIT repository - though I have only checked with:

git ls-files *.suo

No files are returned.

Does this problem have anything to do with a conflict in credentials between TFS/GIT and settings in Visual Studio or Windows? Btw, I am running VS 2013.2 on Win 8.1.

I can't determine if the GIT branch merge really needs access to the VS User Settings file (.suo) or if this file shouldn't even need to be accessed. If it does require access, what could I try to make that happen? If this access isn't needed at all, why does it keep trying?

**EDIT - Additional Info**

I'm new to TFS/GIT. It's a lot to absorb. When I initially setup the repositories (local and TFS on visualstudio.com) the default .gitignore did not get created for some reason, apparently in my local repository? I don't know, but while I was making changes to my project and then making Commits I was seeing things showing up in "Excluded" and "Untracked". Being green to GIT/TFS, I right clicked and included these Excluded/Untracked files. I now know this was wrong.

I think I've recovered from the above problem. First, I implemented a default .gitignore that specifically ignores /bin and /obj. Then I removed everything within those two folders (via VS Solution Explorer). They did not come back up as Included, Excluded or Untracked. This fixed one issue.

Next issue was that I saw the project's .suo included in the v0.43 branch. I saw that it was supposed to be ignored in the default .gitignore (*.suo) and so I needed to remove it from the v0.43 branch, but it wasn't as easy as deleting unused files. I did it from the command line using:

I was able to see that the .suo existed using:

```
git ls-files *.suo
```

I removed it with:

```
git rm --cached "*.suo"
git commit -m "Delete *.suo file from repository"
```

... and I was/am able to confirm it was removed by performing the same ls-files command. It no longer shows up in the v0.43 branch. I made the commit and sync'd with TFS. Now I am getting the error noted above - Access is Denied to the .suo whenever I try to merge v0.43 to master or even switch to master branch.

Possibly it is the master branch that I am trying to switch **TO** that is trying to access the .suo file?

If that's the case, I'm totally stumped on how to resolve this. I suppose it is possible that the .suo got Committed to the master branch at some point... but I don't know how to safely access the master branch and remove the .suo from it like I did to v0.43 branch.

I hope this all makes sense. :S

Comment: "2013.2" means Visual Studio 2013 with update 2? Any reason you haven't updated to update 3 or 4?

Comment: I'm at a critical point in this project and can't afford (or explain) any downtime. Is there something in 3 or 4 that addresses the problem I'm having?

Comment: Not to my knowledge but if you were to contact Microsoft to ask about this, this would be their first suggestion. I don't see why the merge should require write access to this file, just as you say, as long as none of the branches have this file committed. I'm assuming you have verified this specifically, that the files is not part of any changeset? Easy to check, just clone to an empty directory and update to the head of each of the branches. If the file appears, that might explain why you're getting that problem.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I don't have a lot of experience with GIT yet. Creating clones, update to the head of each branch... I don't have any clue how to manage these changes or if I need to be concerned with them. v0.43 contains important code/changes. I updated my question to provide some history. I'm not sure if it will change your recommendation or not.

Comment: After solving this problem (or working around it) and after getting out of your current time crunch, you should make it a priority to learn git and its tools. The ability to experiment by cloning and messing around in a temporary folder is one of the things that makes DVCS' so great.

Comment: Your update indicates that the .suo file was committed in one or both of the branches, and yes, I believe that would cause the problem you're getting. HOWEVER, by removing it from the repository, anyone on your team that updates to a revision after this will potentially lose their local settings (the .suo file) since it might be deleted locally when updating. This is why it is important to ensure these personal files are not committed in the first place.

Comment: There hasn't been anyone else involved yet. This setup was intended as a test pilot that seemed to be going well. I think what you might be telling me is that GIT is trying to remove the .suo from my project folder now? I can understand why that is failing. And YES, I know I need a better understanding of GIT/TFS and GIT's command line options. I'm guessing, but is a solution to somehow remove the .suo from the master as well? Or move the .suo in my project folder to a safe location, then do the merge or switch? Thank you for your comments.

Comment: If at any point in time after this you update first to a revision *before* you deleted the .suo file, your local file will be overwritten with the one present in the repository. If, after this, you then update back to a revision *after* you deleted the .suo file, it will again be deleted. It won't cause much problems though, there's not a lot of important settings stored in there, things like which file you had open last time etc.

Comment: Honestly, I wasn't prepared for GIT and shouldn't have started using the TFS repository when I did. I was prodded though and didn't feel I had much choice. At this point I am very happy with the code in the v0.43 branch. I would like to delete the project on visualstudio.com and use my local repository's v0.43 to push as a brand new master on visualstudio.com. With the end result being that the current branch of v0.43 becomes the remote and local master branch.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen He could just do a filter-branch to remove the .suo file from history, then add it to his .gitignore so that it doesn't pop back up.

Comment: @DanielMann Wouldn't that involve rewriting his repository, changing all the hashes, etc.? Might be possible for him seeing as he is the only developer though.

Comment: I was able to get into the master branch from the command line. I then did an rm --cached *.suo and committed. This allows me to switch to the master branch in VS now! ;)

Answer (score 10):

I got a very similar issue today. I couldn't switch branches because there was this error:

> An error occurred. Detailed message: Could not open 'D:/Projects/ProjectName/Database/database.db' for writing: Access is denied.

*Note: Pathname and filename renamed for display purposes*

What I did was very simple

- Remove the file from your file explorer (not in your project)
- Git will now detect a deletion of this file
- Undo this deletion in your `Changes` view

I'm not sure what caused this problem and I hope anyone finds this answer helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on this right now and believe this to be the answer to the problem-
The *.sou file is part of Visual Studio's user preferences. It's in the ".vs" folder that is a "hidden folder" along side your solution.
If you are using Team Services as your Git repository, then you just need to remove the ".vs" folder and it will be marked "Deleted/{folder}/.vs"

To delete the folder in Team Services: locate the project in Team Services, and hover over the "Code" drop down menu and select "Files". Navigate to the .sln folder and you will find the ".vs" folder. Delete that ".vs" folder by "righ-clicking" on it and selecting "Delete"
That folder should no longer be tracked.

Answer (score 1):

I also get this situation sometime but there is a simple solution for this.

Just delete the .suo file from your project folder

- goto solution explorer and right click on solution and choose second last option named 'open folder in file explorer'.

  [image]
- After that goto .vs folder(This is a hidden folder).
- After that open folder, that has a name of your project.
- Then delete the .sou file in that folder.
- It's done.
- Open your visual studio and you see your problem is solved.

Thank you,
Nishit Zinzuvadiya.